# comma between author and year in harvardstyle Sagej

Tags: bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

I need to insert comma between the name of author and year in Harvard style

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{proposition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2016}
```

I use `\citep{}` in the text, and in the end of my article, I use

```
\bibliographystyle{SageH}
\bibliography{refrencestyle}
```

I need to for example:

> (Phat, 2005; Sun et al., 2006)

but LaTeX gives me

> (Phat 2005; Sun et al. 2006)

without comma

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're loading the `amssymb` package, there can be no valid reason for loading the `latexsym` package as well.

Comment: No, I try it, which dose not work . I delete amssymb and  try !

Comment: No, don't strike `amssymb` off the list! Strike `latexsym`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sagej` document class automatically loads the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package. If you want citation call-outs generated by `\citep` to feature a comma between the author's name and the publication year, all you need to do is issue the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
```

in the preamble.

For more information about the `\setcitestyle` macro (it can do a whole lot more than just instruct LaTeX to insert an extra comma here or there), see pages 12 and 13 of the user guide of the `natbib` package.